# How to use AngularJS promises

Tags: angularjs

How can I use promises to trigger the load method after the download completes successfully in this service?

```
   .service('pdfService', function(){
   var lastUrl;
   var lastFileName
   return {
      createPdf(url, fileName){
          //do processing
          lastUrl = url;
          lastFileName = fileName
      },
      loadLastPdf(){
         //use lastUrl and lastFileName
      }
   }
}
```

and in the controller:

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function(pdfService) {
    pdfService.createPdf('http://example.com', 'file.pdf');
    // or pdfService.loadLastPdf();
}
```

I try within the downloadPdf method but don't receive a response.

```
filetransfer.download(
...
).then(function(){ 
   this.load(lastFileName)
});
```

I am using Cordova file transfer.

Comment: The code in `pdfService` looks syntactically incorrect

Comment: question is really hard to understand with the given code examples... Where exactly is the download done? "this" points to the scope of that anonymous function... I can only recommend reading the official documentation about the promise API: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Here is my complete attempt, being newbie to angular world, it is for an ionic app: http://plnkr.co/edit/ASB7LSCuCRvVLGI3Kqxf?p=preview i am looking for promisses tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this piece of code helps me a lot :

```
controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $q) {

  function longOperation() {
    var q = $q.defer();

    somethingLong(function() {
      q.resolve();
    });    

    return q.promise;
  }

  Then you can call it:

  longOperation().then(function() {

});

})
```